# Angular production build has problem with useHash

Tags: angular

I am facing a strange issue, the below useHash condition is  working fine in dev build but the same condition is not working in the production build.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash:localStorage.getItem("mTenantMode") != "true" })
```

Comment: Please elaborate on _the specific way it_ "is not working". Does it throw an error in the console? Does it fail to compile? What is your production build configuration (angular.json and relevant ng build flags)? What version of angular core and CLI are you using? See [mcve]

Comment: This won't work with AOT, you cannot have a runtime value here the way you do it. And which option property are you trying to set exactly?

Comment: I  have edited the question, @msanford false is always set for useHash property

Comment: @David i am using --prod and not AOT and i am trying for useHash property.

Comment: @msanford i am using Angular CLI: 7.3.9, Node: 10.15.0, OS: win32 x64, 
Angular: 7.2.15 .

Comment: If you do a build with `--prod`, then you are using AOT